# @hook.regist decorate didn't work

Tags: wagtail

just testing wagtaildemo, in the local ubuntu pc use runserver  command can runing well.

in the file "wagtaildemo/demo/wagtail_hooks.py" find have @hook.regist decorate function, but in the admin site lest tab and other place didn't find the function entry. Why?

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.conf import settings

from wagtail.wagtailcore import hooks

@hooks.register('insert_editor_css')
def editor_css():
    return format_html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' +
                       settings.STATIC_URL +
                       'demo/css/admin-streamfield-styles.css">')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/hooks.html#hooks) say:

> Hooks
>
> On loading, Wagtail will search for any app with the file
>   wagtail_hooks.py and execute the contents. This provides a way to
>   register your own functions to execute at certain points in Wagtail’s
>   execution, such as when a Page object is saved or when the main menu
>   is constructed.

So this function is a hook which executes when the admin editor page is created and adds a `link` tag to a CSS file for stylizing the streamfield. [`insert_editor_css`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) hook inserts additional CSS files or snippets.